# Not able to start IntelliJ version 2017.1

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to start the IntelliJ but it failed and showing following error message.

[image]

I have already defined `JAVA_HOME` in system variable. I also tried to update `JAVA_HOME`  in user environment variable. I am expecting the user defined will overwritten system one. However, **IntelliJ** still looking for system defined variable, and tried create JVM from there.

[image]

This issue happened when my admin right has been invoked. It used to work before.

Is there any way I could run the **IntelliJ** without the admin right.

Comment: It seems that you need 32-bit JDK. Is your JDK 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting : `IDEA_JDK` environment variable

> IDEA_JDK={your_jdk_path}
>
> `Example : IDEA_JDK=C:\softwares\jdk1.8.0_66`

Comment: looks like its a windows access issue(as mentioned in above answer) than the JDK/JRE path issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled Intellij with user permission and it works. The reason with the issue was that I had installed Intellij with admin privilege, it stopped working after my local admin have been revoked.